# Algorithms to generate random nowhere-neat rectangulation?

Tags: algorithms, combinatorics, tiling

[image]

I want to generate random [rectangular partition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Fault-FreeRectangle.html) of a given $m*n$ rectangle under the  constraint that it must be nowhere-neat partition. Nowhere-neat partition means that a dissection of a rectangle into smaller rectangles such that the original rectangle is not divided into two subrectangles.

My interest is in generating rectangular partitions that satisfy these two conditions: 1- No two adjacent rectangles share a common side (i.e. the union of two adjacent rectangles is not a rectangle).  2- At most two corners meet at a point.

Similar partitions appear under other names that include rectangulations, Tatami tilings, and non-slicing floorplans.

> What algorithms are there that generate random fault-free rectangular partitions?

Update: 
Here is an example of random [Mondrian rectangular partitions](https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/115945709/). Here the original rectangle is divided into two subrectangles. However, it is the opposite of what I want.

[image]

I do not require uniform distribution. I do not require a specific number of tiles, I only require that the number of tiles $T$ is within some fixed ratio $\epsilon \lt 1$ of $mn$ where $m= \theta(n)$ ($T=\epsilon*m*n$).

Comment: Could it be as simple as choosing some points at random, drawing horizontal and vertical lines through each, then repeatedly choosing at random any point still incident on "rays" in all 4 cardinal directions, choosing a random direction to "clear", and deleting the ray that lies in that direction?

Comment: What do you mean by "random distribution"? A process that always generates the number 5 is still considered a random process.  A random variable that always has the value 5 is still a random variable, and is still considered random.  So, I suspect asking for a random partition isn't capturing what you really want; I suspect you need to tell us something more about what properties you want the distribution to have.  Otherwise, a deterministic algorithm that always output the same tiling would meet all stated requirements.  Please edit the question to clarify all of these points in the question.

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany D.W and you might have different views/feelings towards randomness, one of the most elusive concept in math, physics, etc. Let me continue with the simple academic intention of D.W as well as the question asked by j_random_hacker. Your question is not well-defined enough in the sense that the desired probability distribution of the output is not specified. For example, j_random_hacker has specified [a naive algorithm](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/106729#comment228693_106729). Do you consider that algorithm a valid solution, in term of randomness?

Comment: @MohammadAl-Turkistany in fact, I believe the essence of this question is how to define a probability distribution of the output given $m$ and $n$ (and a few other parameters) that can be considered random intuitively or suitably for your usage. It is quite possible that if that probability distribution is defined clearly, it might be trivial to come up with an algorithm.

Comment: @Apass.Jack Thanks for your comments.  I accept j_random_hacker algorithm as long as it is clear enough to be implemented in a programming language (such as Python or Scratch). For instance here is an algorithm that generates random Mondrian rectangular partitions (it is opposite to what I want):  https://scratch.mit.edu/projects/115945709/

Comment: Thanks.  Following your Mathworld link, it seems that a fault-free partition can indeed contain two rectangles that share a side (provided that some other rectangle exists in the partition with an interior that intersects the line containing this side) -- additionally forbidding such side-sharing rectangles takes us into the realm of "nowhere-neat" partitions.  Please clarify which type of partition you want.

Comment: @j_random_hacker The fault-free partitions that I am interested in are illustrated by the three above examples. I am not interested in "nowhere-neat" partitions.

Comment: @j_random_hacker To clarify, If you dissect a rectangle into two subrectangles then they share a common side (with same length). In other words, in fault-free partitions, the union of two adjacent rectangles is not a rectangle.

Comment: Unfortunately those 3 examples are not only "fault-free", but also meet the stronger conditions of being "nowhere-neat", according to my understanding of the definitions at the Mathworld link.  If you chop the top-right rectangle in the leftmost example in two with a vertical cut that does not coincide with any other line segment, then the resulting partition would *remain* "fault-free" but no longer be "nowhere-neat".  If that doesn't clarify things, please describe what you understand to be the difference between these two conditions ("fault-free" and "nowhere-neat").

Comment: "In other words, in fault-free partitions, the union of two adjacent rectangles is not a rectangle" -- according to my understanding, that's exactly the definition of nowhere-neat, not fault-free.  A fault-free partition $X$ may contain such pairs of rectangles, but there must not be a partition $X = A \sqcup B$ such that $\bigcup A$ forms a rectangle and $\bigcup B$ forms a rectangle.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I see. Then I am looking for fault-free and nowhere-neat partitions.

Comment: @j_random_hacker But why did Mathworld list those three examples under fault-free dissections?

Comment: @j_random_hacker Let us forget about terminology. My interest is in partitions that satisfy these two conditions: 1) No two adjacent rectangles share a common side (i.e. the union of two adjacent rectangles is not a rectangle).  2) At most two corners meet at a point.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: The examples *are* FF -- every NN partition is also FF (but not vice versa).  They just aren't good examples, because they accidentally also fall into the stronger category of NN.  The criteria in your "Let us forget about terminology" message are exactly the NN conditions, as I understand them, so please edit (again) to remove all occurrences of "fault-free" (you could replace each occurrence with "nowhere-neat").

Comment: @j_random_hacker I edited the post as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4231713/166353